# Simple django POST not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="{% url "forum.posts" forum=forum.slug thread=thread.slug %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Začni tipkati.."></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Pošlji odgovor">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
'''
Display all posts in a thread or create a new post in a thread.
'''
def posts(request, forum, thread):
    forum = Forum.objects.get(slug=forum)

    thread = Thread.objects.get(slug=thread)

    if request.method == "POST":

        return HttpResponse('ok')

    posts = thread.posts.all()

    return render(request, 'forum/posts.html', {
        'forum': forum,
        'thread': thread,
        'posts': posts
    })
```

**urls.py (relevant part):**

```
# List all posts in a thread / Submit a post to a forum
url(r'^(?P<forum>[-\w]+)/(?P<thread>[-\w]+)/$', 'forum.views.posts', name='forum.posts'),
```

**HTML output:**

```
<form action="/forum/o-spletiscu/novatemaa/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="4PQWDsAfHyjrhUnYU5P9vVhtaY3vLPBU">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="post-body" class="form-control" placeholder="Začni tipkati.."></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Pošlji odgovor">
</form>
```

After I hit submit, I expect `ok` to be returned, instead page refreshes and nothing happens.
Normal GET requests are working though..

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
It's working when I use `@csrf_exempt` on `posts` method.

Comment: It looks like the `url` pattern don't match. Can you include the Html?.

Answer (score 1):

> page refreshes and nothing happens

Problem with your action value. try to inspect it and find wither the url is correct or not.

OR

your form does not have any input with `name` property.

Try this:

```
  <form action="{% url "forum.posts" forum=forum.slug thread=thread.slug %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Začni tipkati.." name="something"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Pošlji odgovor">
  </form>
```

Comment: Still not working, even with a name attribute added. I've checked the action value and it seems alright. I must be missing something trivial but I just can't see it.

Comment: try to change the action property to hard coded url.